# module 'pandas_datareader.data' has no attribute 'Datareader'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance

I am trying to run the code below, I am using Spyder. I have another file that also uses pandas_datareader, and I never get an error message on that file, which is also run on Spyder. In addition the other file also uses yahoo, so I don't think that is the issue either. My questions is:is there something particular in my code that is causing this file to not have a data reader module?

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests

def save_sp500_tickers():
     resp=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers=[]
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker=row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open('sp500tickers.pickle','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)
    print(tickers)

    return tickers
#save_sp500_tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):

    if reload_sp500:
        tickers=save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open('sp500tickers.pickle','rb') as f:
            tickers=pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')
    start=dt.datetime(2016,1,1)
    end=dt.datetime(2019,5,27)

    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df=web.Datareader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}' .format(ticker))
get_data_from_yahoo()
```

Comment: It is misspelt: needs a capital 'R': DataReader instead of Datareader

Comment: I tried capitalizing it too, still doesn't work

Comment: Is the error different?

Comment: DId you get the answer for this question? I am also facing the same issue..

Comment: Unfortunately, I never did. Let me know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
```

then use:

```
data.DataReader('path')
```

to read the file